# How to integrate square payment gateway in Strapi cms

Tags: integration, payment, strapi, square

I want to add square payment gateway in strapi cms.

I have tried with different method it's not integrating.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you have any additional details? What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the Stripe plugin for your app? https://market.strapi.io/plugins/strapi-stripe